# Linux - override version of software called

Tags: linux, bash

I use a cluster, and want to run a particular version of R when 'R' is typed on the command line from any folder. I can't do `make install` as this requires root privileges.

I've tried appending the path to my desired version before and then after the PATH variable. However, when I hit 'R' on the shell, it still loads the undesired version.

---

This is what I tried:

```
$ export R_HOME="/scratch/mcp50/paks/R-3.2.0/bin/R"
$ export PATH="$R_HOME:$PATH"
$ R
WARNING: ignoring environment value of R_HOME

R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing"
```

Comment: Certainly PATH, and probably R_HOME, should refer to the containing directories. You *probably* want `R_HOME="/scratch/mcp50/paks/R-3.2.0/"` and `PATH="${R_HOME}/bin:$PATH"`. You are *probably* getting the WARNING because $R_HOME/something is not being found by R starting up.

Comment: *hangs head in shame* I'd pointed PATH to the binary, rather than the directory it was in.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, the default version of `R` can be ascertained with the following command:

```
which R
```

The `which` command performs a search for the `R` executable using the system `PATH`.

For versions of `R` installed by system package managers (e.g. `r-base` on Debian or Ubuntu) this will be `/usr/bin/R`. For versions of `R` installed from source this will typically (but not always) be located in `/usr/local/bin/`.

If you want to override which version of `Rscript` is used then you can explicitly specify the path inside your `bash` script like such:

```
/my/path/to/Rscript script1.R
```

Outside of using `bash` to specify which installation of `rscript` to use, you can run your script directly from the command-line by editing the first line of your `R` script is like the following `#!/usr/bin/Rscript` (replacing `/usr/bin` with your actual `R` executable installation directory).

What is unclear from your question is--have you been able to get an alternate version of `R` on the target system?

Comment: Thanks, but my question is very specific: I need to control the default version opened by the system without root access.

Answer (score 0):

I'd pointed PATH to the binary, rather than the directory it was in. – conjectures